# Angular App makes duplicate http requests after idling a couple of hours

Tags: angular

stack: Angular 7, nodejs backend, postgresql database, firebase auth

Problem: if I make an http request on my angular app and then let it idle in the background for a couple of hours, it makes duplicate http requests.  It always makes the same amount of duplicate requests, which is an additional 2.  It does this on the ENTIRE app.  The duplicate requests occur with zero user input after the initial request and typically occur a couple of hours later.

Could this happen when a user comes back and firebase does some sort of re-authentication request? At this point, I'm at a loss for what the issue could be

Comment: Make sure not to leave active subscriptions. It is a good practice to unsubscribe observables. This [post](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f) may help you.

Comment: even on http requests?  Thanks for the reply, much appreciate